# Two approaches to computing angle between two real vectors in higher dimensions.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $u,v$ be a pair of linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The angle between the two vectors $\theta$ is given by $\arccos \left( \dfrac{u \cdot v}{\|u\| \|v\|} \right)$ where the dot product is defined as
$u\cdot v=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} u_k v_k$

Let $W$ be the vector subspace generated by $u$ and $v$. As $W$ has dimension $2$, we should be able to find an orthonormal transformation $T$ from $W$ to $R^2$ (preserving the inner products). We could then normalize $Tu$ and $Tv$, and call the resulting vectors $u1$ and $v1$ respectively. As $u1$ and $v1$ are two vectors lying on the unit circle, we could compute the angle in radians between $u1$ and $v1$ using the arc length definition of angle. We could then define the angle between $u$ and $v$ in $R^n$ to be the angle between $u1$ and $v1$ in $R^2$.

I think the two methods of computing the angle between $u$ and $v$ should coincide as $T$ was orthonormal.

If so, is there a formula/transformation that gives us $u1$ and $v1$ in $R^2$, given $u$ and $v$ in $R^n$. Alternatively what is the matrix of $T$ with respect to the standard basis, or any other appropriate basis.

Apologies for changing the question as I am attempting to more precise about what is confusing me.

Comment: The idea is that the angle between the two vectors in space is the angle between the two measured on the two-dimensional subspace they define, like you said. Think of it like finding a plane they both lie 'in' and treating it like $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: @oldrinb Thanks. Is there a 'mechanical' way to find such a plane and the vectors $u1$ and $v1$ as defined above?

Comment: you want to map say $u\mapsto(0,1)$ and then map some vector orthogonal to $u$ yet lying in the subspace to $(1,0)$. This should uniquely determine the matrix columns.

Comment: @oldrinb I am presuming you mean to do the following steps. Step 1: Map $\frac{u}{\|u\|}\mapsto(0,1)$. Step 2: Find a unit vector $w$ orthogonal to $u$ yet lying in $W$ using Gram-Schmidt. Step 3: Map $w\mapsto(1,0)$. That should define the Matrix.

Comment: use Gram-Schmidt on $u,v$ to determine orthonormal ${u',v'}$. The matrix which maps $u'\mapsto(0,1),v'\mapsto(1,0)$ is the one with $u',v'$ as rows:$$\begin{bmatrix}u'\\v'\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @oldrinb - I think the matrix should be the identity, as $T(v')=(1,0)^T$ & $T(u')= (0,1)^T$, with the order of the basis ${v',u'}$ for $W$ and ${(1,0), (0,1)}$ for $R^2$. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you project them at first, you could change the angle between them. Think of $(0,0,1)^T$ and $(1,0,0)^T$. The method mentioned above is our normal definition.

Comment: @ Dominic - I edited the question to reflect to reflect your comment. Maybe it's more clear now.

Comment: @dyuta draw a circle and remember that the euclidian scalar product  has the property that $u\cdot v= \|u\| \cdot \|v\| \cdot \cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them

Comment: @ Dominic - Thanks. Your comments have been very helpful in improving my understanding of what it is that is confusing me. Please see my changes to the question. Thanks.